# Multisheet and JxlsHelper#setDeleteTemplateSheet

Tags: jxls

I am using `mutlisheet` to generate multiple sheets from an XLSX-Template.
It works, but the resulting Excel-File contains (besides the generated sheets) the template-sheet.
I found the method `JxlsHelper#setDeleteTemplateSheet` but it does not seem to have any impact.

Code:

```
try (InputStream template = ...;
    OutputStream out = ...) {

    Context context = new Context();
    context.putVar(...);
    JxlsHelper.getInstance().setDeleteTemplateSheet(true).processTemplate(template, out, context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe custom a JxlsHelper extends official JxlsHelper.class and override the method JxlsHelper#processTemplate(Context context, Transformer transformer) is a strategy,
code like this:

```
 @Override
public void processTemplate(Context context, Transformer transformer) throws IOException {
    AreaBuilder areaBuilder = this.getAreaBuilder();
    boolean processFormulas = this.isProcessFormulas();

    areaBuilder.setTransformer(transformer);
    List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
    Iterator var4 = xlsAreaList.iterator();

    Area xlsArea;
    while (var4.hasNext()) {
        xlsArea = (Area) var4.next();
        xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef(xlsArea.getStartCellRef().getCellName()), context);
    }

    if (processFormulas) {
        var4 = xlsAreaList.iterator();

        while (var4.hasNext()) {
            xlsArea = (Area) var4.next();
            this.setFormulaProcessor(xlsArea);
            xlsArea.processFormulas();
        }
    }

    logger.info("===================delete template sheet in CusJxlsHelper");
    if (this.isDeleteTemplateSheet()) {
        transformer.deleteSheet("TEMPLATE");
    }

    transformer.write();
}

// realize any method if neccessary.
```

then, use your custom jxlsHelper to replace the official JxlsHelper. it works!

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here:

```
JxlsHelper.getInstance().setUseFastFormulaProcessor(false).setDeleteTemplateSheet(true).processTemplate(is, os, context);
```

did not work. Found workaround:

```
Workbook templ = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(templ);
AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
List<Area> areaList = areaBuilder.build();
Area xlsArea = areaList.get(0);
xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet!A1"), context);
templ.removeSheetAt(0);
templ.write(os);
```